# PHP Post radio value to next page on radio click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need some help with my code as I have got a problem with posting the value. When I click on the radio, it will not post the data when it redirect me to secondpage.php. I want to post the value when I click on the radio button to take me to the next page.

**firstpage.php**

```
<table>
    <form name="frmProfile" method="post" action="secondpage.php">
        <tr>
            <td>gender</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="document.location.href='http://example.com/secondpage.php'" data-gender="female" value="female">Female
                <input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="document.location.href='http://example.com/secondpage.php'" data-gender="male" value="male">Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
    </form>     
</table>
```

**secondpage.php**

```
print_r($_POST);

?>
```

It will show the empty data in the `$_POST` as I will get the results which it show `Array ( )` when I am using `print_r($_POST)` in secondpage.php.

What I am trying to achieve is when I click on a radio button, I want to post the data to redirect me to `secondpage.php` and display the data of `Male` or `Female` depends on the radio button that I click on.

Can you please show me an example how I could post the value of the radio that I select on to redirect me to the secondpage.php to display the data of `$_POST`?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would it?  Changing window.location.href is performing a GET request to the new page, without any data

Comment: @Taplar Oh I see, so what do I have to use then? do I have to use `$_GET` in secondpage.php or what?

Comment: you can send the value of checkbox in url as param, and using `$_GET` in the second page.

Comment: Well first off before we go any further, I should ask.  if you want the form to submit when they change the radio, why do you have the submit button?

Comment: Assign an id for the form e.g. `id="gender"`. Change the onclick event of the radio buttons to `document.getElementById("gender").submit();` Your current onclick event only redirect the page to `secondpage.php`, not submit the form, that's why your POST data is empty.

Comment: @illuminarch I dont want to use checkbox because I want to use the radio button to allow my clients to unsubscribe from my list.

Comment: sorry i mean radio button, haha.

Comment: @catcon is `onclick="document.getElementById("gender").submit();'"` the correct one I should use?

Comment: @Taplar Well I want to use the radio click to make it more easy without you have to click on a button. So how do you post the value when you click on the radio button?

Comment: @illuminarch oh I get you, so can you show me an example how I could use to send the value of radio in url as param so I could use `$_GET` in the second page?

Comment: you can do in many ways, this one them `<input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="document.location.href='http://example.com/secondpage.php?value=female'" data-gender="female" value="female">` and in second page you can do this `$_GET['value']`

Comment: @illuminarch Thank you for this, but I prefer to use `$_POST` method because I am using the long id in the url as a param so I dont want the value to be seen in the url. So do you know how I could post the value so I could use `$_POST` in the second page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a click event listener to the form.  When a click happens, check if it originated from one of the radio elements.  If it did, submit the form.

```js
document.getElementById('genderForm').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                                  // 'this' is the genderForm
  if (e.target.name === 'gender') this.submit();
});
```

```html
<form id="genderForm" name="frmProfile" method="post" action="secondpage.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>gender</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this as this is what I am looking for exactly. Problem are now resolved.